# Does ArcGIS Online support versioning?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-online, versioning

Using ArcSDE with a relational database, it is possible to set up [versioning](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000t7000000). Is this available in ArcGIS Online, aka ArcGIS.com?

When working with a feature layer in ArcGIS Online, there is the option to allow editing, and to ensure only the feature's creator can make changes. But this isn't the same thing as fully-fledged versioning, allowing the ability to merge conflicts, etc.

[image]

Is versioning supported using ArcGIS Online?

Comment: All databases are read-only in ArcGIS for Server Enterprise Basic edition and read/write in ArcGIS for Server Enterprise Standard/Advanced http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/~/media/Files/Pdfs/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf

Comment: @mapperz thanks, but the bit I'm struggling with is how that corresponds to ArcGIS Online. I can't see anything which explicitly states that AGOL does/does not support versioning

Comment: AGOL is a huge server farm hosting services.  There are certainly enterprise geodatabases in the back end, and you could certainly integrate your own ArcGIS Server through Portal, but it's unlikely that you'd have exclusive access to an Esri enterprise geodatabase unless such a service was published for that purpose.  This question is something of a non sequitur, because you are crossing domain boundaries between components of the ArcGIS platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no control over setting up versioning in hosted feature services in ArcGIS Online.  There is nothing stopping you from registering your ArcGIS for Server services with ArcGIS Online in a hybrid approach.  These ArcGIS for Server services can be pointing to a specific version within the GeoDatabase.  Let me know via comments if you need further clarification.

Comment: If its a Q&A workflow your after, there are some scripts that will sync edits between two separate feature services based upon the editor time stamp.  Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Yes please, a link to these scripts would be helpful :)